# TFS Shell Extension error TF246017 The Team foundation server could not connect to database

Tags: azure-devops, tfs

Our team just switched from TFS on premise to Azure Devops. I use the TFS Shell Extension. I Visual Studio, I changed the connection to the new server. I has assumed that the TFS Shell Extension would just use the new connection. But I am getting this error:

```
TF246017
Team foundation server could not connect to the database. 
Verify that the server that is hosting the database is operational.
```

How do I tell the extension that I have to change the connection?

Comment: Note that I did try to reboot as I had read that was the solution. But it didn't work for me. Also note that VS is now connected to the new TFS server, and I can do source control operations there.

Comment: I also tried in Control Panel, "repair" and "reboot"